# Run code after css gets loaded but before images are downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website, The problem being faced is

Images take time to download, on my system it takes around 20 seconds to download the complete website. Their is a loader being shown which hides on window.load event i.e. when complete website gets loaded(20 seconds).

If i hide the loader on document.ready event, website shows up fast, good for the user. But here the problem is that some content is shown without applying CSS for about 2 seconds which looks odd.

I am looking for a way to hide the loader as soon as css gets loaded while the images aren't.

Comment: Your website shouldn't take 20 seconds to load. You should take time to optimize your website. You can use this tool to analyse what should be optimized on your website - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: You might also want to optimise you images and try lazy loading them as a measure of last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done in the past which may work for you is swapping the image `src` for a `data-src` like so:

```
<img src="" data-src="your-image.jpg" alt="some alt description">
```

Then all you need to do is add some JavaScript that loops over the DOM swapping the data-src for src:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src') = $(this).data('src');
    });
});
```

The advantages of this technique are that you webpage will render the CSS before all the images are loaded. And that also means the page will load really fast.
The potential disadvantage is that this is not good for image SEO (Google or Bing images)